# Show that $\langle x^{2}+1\rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $R[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $I=\langle x^{2}+1\rangle.$

Consider A be an ideal containing $I$ properly .
How can I prove that A contains some nonzero number?
After that I can do it

Comment: Does $\,R = \Bbb R?\ \ $

Answer (score 3):

You're supposing $\langle x^2+1\rangle\subsetneq A\subsetneq \mathbb{R}[x]$.

Pick an $f\in A\setminus I$ and consider the remainder of $f$ divided by $x^2+1$. What form must it take? What can you do with that element and $x^2+1$? (Remeber, you're aiming to get a constant.)

Answer (score 3):

*Hint for an alternative solution:* Consider the ring homomorphism $\mathbb R[x] \to \mathbb C$ given by $f(x) \mapsto f(i)$. Prove that it is surjective and find its kernel.

Answer (score 2):

If it was not a maximal ideal, $(x^2+1)\subset (p)$, you would have $x^2+1=p(x)q(x)$ where $p,q$ are not constant, and their degree is $1$. This implies that $x^2+1$ has a root, contradiction.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question asked ("how can I prove $A$ contains....")

Answer (score 1):

**Hint** $\ p= x^2\!+1\,$ is irreducible so $\ f\not\in (p)\,\Rightarrow\, p\nmid f\,\Rightarrow\, 1 = \gcd(f,p) =  a f + b p\in (f,p) $

Comment: I presume that $\,R = \Bbb R\,$ (or any field where $x^2+1$ is irreducible). Otherwise it has a proper factor $f$ so $(x^2+1)\subsetneq (f)\subsetneq (1)\ $ so it is not maximal.